# Migration of elasticsearch java Client from 1.4.2 to 7.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Currently i am running elasticsearch in 1.4.2 and I trying to make it run in 7.2, the problem that I found is in the method `filteredQuery(MatchAllQueryBuilder, String, String)` and `filteredQuery(MatchAllQueryBuilder, QueryBuilder[])` of the class `FilterBuilders` (this class was replaced by `QueryBuilders`), I didn't found any alternative method knowing that they are removed in 7.2, but for this implementation of `filteredQuery`:

`filteredQuery(QueryBuilder,QueryBuilder)` I found that I should use `boolquery()` with filter clause and it works. See more in :
(https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilder.html) filterBuilder).

My question is what are the alternative method for `filteredQuery(MatchAllQueryBuilder, String, String)` and `filteredQuery(MatchAllQueryBuilder, QueryBuilder[])`.

Please, if there's any suggestion, do not hesitate to ask.
Thank you!

*source:
(https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilder.html))

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is as you already found the answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: my question is what should i use instead of filteredQuery(MatchAllQueryBuilder, String, String) and filteredQuery(MatchAllQueryBuilder, QueryBuilder[]) (i have found 3 implementation for filteredQuery  ) the filteredQuery with two parameter ( filteredQuery(QueryBuilder,QueryBuilder)) i  found the methode to use instead of it  boolquery() . the other two method i still didn't found what I should use instead !

Comment: The notion of a "filtered query" from ES 1.x (i.e. - a non-scoring "filter" and a scoring "query") was entirely replaced by functionality from a bool query, which now has `must`/`must_not`/`should` clauses for scoring, and `filter` clauses for non-scoring.  If you were using `QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(query, filter)` in ES 1.x, you'll want to convert your `filter` to a `QueryBuilder` (should be straightforward) and then use `QueryBuilders.must(query).filter(filter)` in ES 7.x

Comment: @rusnyder The method must() is undefined for the type QueryBuilders

Comment: Gah - my bad.  I missed a crucial part, and meant to suggest `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(query).filter(filter)`

Comment: yes you're right but what should i do with The method filteredQuery (MatchAllQueryBuilder, String, String) .

Comment: I'm not sure where in the ES API you're finding that method, but I'm unable to locate it.  Could you share the class you're finding that method in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196265/discussion-between-rusnyder-and-mamamia).

Comment: no problem , thanks !